# Using XSLT 1.0, how to you grab just the first word of a string to save to a variable

Tags: xslt-1.0

Does anyone know of a good template to use that works with XSLT 1.0?

**Example:**

string = "Hello my dear friends how are you doing"

I want the word "Hello" and nothing else.

Comment: It depends on how you define "word". -- P.S. Please review: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, it depends on how you define "word" - or more precisely, word separators. In your example, it is trivial to extract `"Hello"` using:

```
substring-before($string, ' ')
```

However, it will not work as well with, say:

```
"Hello, my dear friends: how are you doing?"
```

or:

```
"Hello/Bye alternatives."
```

Comment: My apologies. "Word" as in how regularly people use it...in this example the "word separator" will always be a space(" ") following it which defines the "word".

Comment: Substring before should do the trick. It is just going to look for the first space and grab everything before it, correct?

Comment: "*"Word" as in how regularly people use it..*" Yeah, well, computers are not people. -- Anyway, if you are confident that the first word is followed by a space, you have your answer.

Comment: "*It is just going to look for the first space and grab everything before it, correct?*" Correct: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before If your string can contain a single word only, concatenate a space to the end of it, before calling `substring-before()`.

Comment: @user1869407: You can always throw in a `translate` to change common punctuation to a space before using `substring-before`.

Comment: @corretge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_Cairo

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **generic solution** using the **[FXSL Functional programming library for XSLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/fxsl/)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
      <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' ,:?./&#xA;'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
Hello, my dear friends: how are you doing?
Buy/Sell recommendations.
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<word>Hello</word>
<word>my</word>
<word>dear</word>
<word>friends</word>
<word>how</word>
<word>are</word>
<word>you</word>
<word>doing</word>
<word>Buy</word>
<word>Sell</word>
<word>recommendations</word>
<word/>
```

**Explanation**:

This code calls the FXSL template **[`str-split-to-words`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/strSplit-to-Words.xsl?revision=1.2&view=markup&sortby=file)**.
One can specify the `$pDelimiters` parameter to contain a string, any single character of which is a delimiter to be recognized in the tokenization.

**Do note**: It is assumed that the stylesheet module is saved as a file in the same directory, where FXSL resides -- otherwise the `<xsl:import>` directive will need to be modified with the exact filepath to this directory.

The **fundamentals of FXSL** are explained here: **http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/**